# can't apply alpha to a button image on png layer

Tags: editing

I have 4 png layers (3 display text and 1 displays a button) in AE. When I apply rectangle + alpha it works for txt, but when i apply alpha to button, the rectangular does not disappear but becomes as a size of the button. How to solve this please?